# Is Claims Based Authentication more secure than Basic Authentication?

Tags: security, basic-authentication, saml, claims-based-identity

I have been a developer in the services world for using either basic authentication (in combination use with SSL for securing the transport) or of using claims based authentication (in .NET using WIF).

I think this question has a definitive answer based on the overall *strength* factors that comprise the different authentication mechanisms. This is not a comparison of basic authentication's simplicity vs. CBA's ability to have SSO and a centralized authentication store.

The arguments I've heard against basic authentication is that you can not truly identify the user is who they say they are. If the credentials are compromised one can be spoofed. Apparently with CBA, signing say a SAML token to guarantee the issuance and identity makes this a more thorough method of authorization? However if I have the user's credentials regardless, can't I still get through CBA onto the service as well?

Is this true and CBA is a more thorough and secure method of preforming authentication of users? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CBA can be more secure but it depends on the configuration at the IDP side. If the IDP merely requires a username and password to issue a token then for the reasons you explained it doesn't seem to be more secure.

I am going to use AD FS as the IDP here to illustrate how it can be more a secure option than doing mere basic authentication. ADFS can be configured to disable endpoints that aren't as secure. You can also configure AD FS to do 2FA or MFA based authentication before issuing claims. In these scenarios, because obtaining the claim is harder and if the app is only accessible by CBA, it does indeed become more secure.

The advantage of CBA is not merely the more secure methods of authentication that can be enforced. Its the benefits to the developer in simplifying getting the user attributes by offloading that to the IDP. I believe you already know this but for future readers of this thread the "
[Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/)" is likely a good read.